# alternatively change selection of values

Tags: angular

I want to change the strike of batsman on button click of 1 run and 3 runs.
SP1 is the Html and SP2 is typescript method[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEgdM.png)

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbRAR.jpg)
[image]

Thank You in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [ask] and edit your question so that people may be able to help you. As it stands your question doesn't include enough information for anyone to provide an answer.

Comment: Can you provide the related code?